# Unknown action type: change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I've read a lot of posts here and none of them worked for me. I have a very basic VueJS app but I have an error when I write something in my first component. Here's my code :

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

**store.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        item: ''
    },
    mutations: {
        change(state, item) {
            state.item = item
        }
    },
    actions: {
        change({ commit }, newValue) {
            commit('change', newValue);
        }
    },
    getters: {
        item: item => state.item
    }
})
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <AddItem/>
    <DisplayItem/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import AddItem from './components/AddItemComponent'
import DisplayItem from './components/DisplayItemComponent'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    AddItem,
    DisplayItem
  }
}
</script>
```

**AddItemComponent.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <label for="item">Nom de l'objet</label><br/>
        <input type="text" name="item" @input="changed">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        changed: function (event) {
            this.$store.dispatch('change', event.target.value)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**DisplayItemComponent.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>Nom de l'objet : {{ $store.getters.item }}</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

**...and finally my error**

[image: Error]

As I said, I tried a lot of things but none of them worked... Maybe I forget something ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `mutations` needs to be called `actions`, as you dispatch to an action.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tried replacing `mutations` by `actions` in my store.js but I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `dispatch` to an `action`, then in the action, `commit` the value which will run your `mutation`. Also your state should be an object and not a function.

Here is a basic example:

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        item: ''
    },
    mutations: {
        change(state, item) {
            state.item = item
        }
    },
    actions: {
        change({ commit }, modifiedValue) {
          // do some stuff
          commit('change', modifiedValue)
        }
    },
    getters: {
        item: item => state.item
    }
})
```

You should then be able to run your dispatch now:

```
this.$store.dispatch('change', event.target.value)
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't work... I tried anything you're asking me to do, but I got the same error. I updated my code in my question...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found my problem... I was importing the wrong `store`. Here's my final code and it's working !

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store/store'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Thanks for any help !